# Visual Basic code from Microsoft Access does not work

Tags: ms-access-2010

```
Private Sub cmdAdd_Click()
'add data to table
   CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO Products(ProductCode, ProductName, Category, UnitPrice, UnitCost, QuantityInStock, SupplierCode) " & _
          " VALUES (" & Me.txtProductCode & " , '" & Me.txtProductName & "' , '" & Me.cboCategory & "' , '" & Me.txtUnitPrice & "' , '" & Me.txtUnitCost & "' , '" & Me.txtQuantityInStock & "' , '" & Me.cboSupplierCode & "')"
   'refresh data on list of form
   ProductsSub.Form.Requery
End Sub
```

the code above is suppose to record the data that has been input from the interface, but it does not do anything. The same format of code was used in a different form and it worked. Really weird, but i don't how it was possible.

Comment: No sir. But a code with the same formatting has run in a different form. Could it be a fault in the naming of the values or is it just really a faulty code? Really need help sir. Just a newbie using VB.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to debug this. One of the values you are referencing visa the Me object is not resolving. Place a breakpoint on the CurrentDB.Execute command, and hover over each Me reference (i.e. Me.txtProductCode) to make sure it is obtaining the correct value for the insert. If you have moved this to a library, you may want to use CodeDB.Execute instead of CurrentDB.Execute. I would also check the table to see if the actual INSERT is working as there may be an issue with the Requery event.

Comment: PS. Sometimes the Event gets disconnected from the control. Look at the Command Buttons properties in Form Design view, and on the Onclick event, make sure it says "Event Procedure". The code may not even be running.